# Why should the length property at hibernate mapping file be a power of 2?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have read somewhere that the length property at the hibernate mapping file should be power of 2 i.e. it should be either 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ... and so on. Is it correct? And if so: What is that for?

Comment: Define what you mean by "the length property at the hibernate mapping file".

Comment: I belive that he means this property. In the not so good old times it was set in xml but thanks to $DEITY&&CODERS now we can set it by annotations.

 http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/mapping/Column.html#setLength(int)

Answer (score 0):

The length of a property in hibernate will be mapped to the length of the database field. Should yo really use a power of two?

1. Your application requirements go first. If you have a employee number
   with 15 characters don't make the field 16 just to be a power of 2.
2. If you need to choose a length limit it could save a few bits of
   hard disk depedending on the database and the type of the field.
   Does it really matters nowadays to save disk?
3. I cant beaware of all the performance details with so many databases, versions, engines or configurations. May be Varchar(255) is fast in DummySQL 4.3.1 and varchar(256) is imlemented as a clob. But culd be than in version 4.4 they fixed that limitation. That's why big organizations have a database administrator.

Apart from that I am not aware of any Hibernate specific limitation or cause that makes it advisable to use powers of 2. Just do not forget to add the length